# How to create and use new CSS at run time in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, infragistics, webdatagrid

I am making a configuration entry in web.config that will be used to set background color of cell in `Infragistics WebDataGrid` at runtime.

The infragistic grid only supports css to set colors, so we need to create new CSS class for that color at runtime.

Comment: I am assuming that you are looking to style the cell based on certain conditions and that the color will not change dynamically.  Is that the case and if so, why don't you create the style one time in a css file so that it is cached on client machines and only requested the one time.

Comment: How is the web.config entry that you are making relevant to styling an individual cell?  If you are looking to change the color based on the web.config, maybe it would be better to have multiple classes that you could use defined in your css and use the web.config to set which class you use.